# In VB6, using the FilesSystemObject, how to access directories on multiple servers?

Tags: server, vb6, filesystemobject

In a project we have a table with the following fields:  `FolderPath, FileType, DaysToKeep, ServerIP`.

When the utility is executed, I read the `rs` from the table then want to access the `[ServerIP]\[FolderPath]` to see of the delta of `Now()` and the first file's (or a file's) last save date is greater than `DaysToKeep`.

I have most of the pseudo-code done and am confident in being able to do this on a local server using the `FileSystemObject` (importing Microsoft Scripting Runtime).

```
rsDirectoryList.MoveFirst
Do While Not rsDirectoryList.EOF
    ' Fields: FolderPath, FileType, DaysToKeep, ServerIP

    Debug.Print "Values: " & rsDirectory.Fields("FolderPath").Value

    ' get directory contents from [ServerIP]:[FolderPath]
    'fileSpec = rsDirectory.Fields("ServerIP") & rsDirectory.Fields("FolderPath")

    Set f = fso.GetFile(fileSpec)

    Debug.Print "Last Modified: " & f.DateLastModified & vbNewLine

    ' Get the date of the first file from [ServerIP]\[FolderPath]


    ' If Now() - FileDate in days > DaysToKeep, purge directory
    'If DateDiff("d", Now(), f.DateLastModified) > rsDirectory.Fields("DaysToKeep").Value Then
    '    ' Delete files from specified directory
    '    Kill (serverIP \ FolderPath)   ?????
    'Else
    '    Debug.Print "Skipping: " & rsDirectory.Fields(0).Value & vbNewLine
    'End If


    rs1.MoveNext
Loop
```

I was thinking that I may have to create a share for each server on the utility's server and access them by drive letter, rather than by IP address.

Is there a way to do this with the given IP addresses?

Comment: `Kill "\\" & serverIP & "\" & FolderPath & "\*.*"`?

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem you are having is. It seems like your DB has sufficient information to locate the folders / files... is the issue how to correctly for a path based on a server IP address? In which case, @GSerg 's comment has it.